# Show conflict diff part of a merge

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I need to present to the team what changes I've made during conflict resolution of a merge.

I know this is kind of hard, but I certainly believe it is possible somehow. I've tried already `git show -m` and `git show -c`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the hash (or tag) of the merge commit (the commit that has multiple parents) and do:

```
git diff hash hash^1 hash^2
```

It will output a 3 way-diff of the changes.

`hash^` (or `hash^1`) references the *first* parent commit of `hash`
`hash^2` references the *second* parent commit of `hash`

Comment: _In addition, making that `git diff --cc hash hash^1 hash^2` will format the diff in the same way `gitk` displays it. Not sure which output format is preferred by OP, though..._ Actually, never mind... `git diff` does that by default, it seems, when you give it three hashes...

Comment: thank you! made an alias: `dc = "!f() { HASH=$1; shift 1; git d --cc $HASH $HASH^1 $HASH^2 $@; }; f"`

Comment: When I use this line, I get

`fatal: ambiguous argument 'hash': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]>`

Comment: Dude, you have to replace `hash` with **a real hash** or commit tag of a **merge commit**...

Comment: great answer!  When I look at the [manpage for git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) it doesn't show a variant with three hashes... yet this works for me (git 1.9.1).  Is this an undocumented thing?  It would be nice if I cound read the docs about this nifty new option.

Comment: @stochastic TBH, I don't remember, maybe it was in older versions of the documentation?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for conflicts that were resolved with "ours".

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
git diff ORIG_HEAD MERGE_HEAD(or FETCH_HEAD)
```

`MERGE_HEAD` holds for your local merged files, `ORIG_HEAD` is the commit possible conflicting that you want to merge.

`FETCH_HEAD` is the hash for the repo you fetch changes before merging.

As said above, `PULL` only does fetch (in the remote repo, possible origin) and a `Merge`

In case of doubt see your `.git` folder to see the files where hashes are being stored.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the standard `gitk` tool, and click on a merge commit, the lower left pane shows the conflict resolutions.

Comment: @brauliobo I would assume by doing `git diff hash hash^1 hash^2` where `hash` is the hash of the merge commit.