# Is there a way to get all conflicting code snippets (not just files) after a git merge?

Tags: linux, git, unix, github, gerrit

Once I execute the `git merge A B` command, I can get the list of conflicting files using linux command like

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

But, is there a way to get conflicting code snippets along with file names? I want to create a report with just the conflicting code snippets.

For example, I need a report like this

```
src/com/xyz/ABC.java
<<<<<<< Branch_A
    this.codeFromA();
=======
    this.codeFromB();
>>>>>>>  Branch_B
```

..and the same section repeats for all conflicting files.

Note that there are other lines in the files.  But, only the conflicting code piece is returned.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573555/show-conflict-diff-part-of-a-merge ?

Comment: @Holloway The answer in the thread you pointed to shows all diffs. Whereas i want only the conflicting diffs. Thanks for the pointer though :)

Answer (score 1):

Just run `git diff`.

[Here](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#idp15367824) is explained how it works:

> Since Git stages any merge results that are successful, when you run git diff while in a conflicted merge state, you only get what is currently still in conflict

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, you can get this information from Git staging view.

Comment: I am trying to get this report by running a script on a Jenkins server.  So, I will not have access to Eclipse that way.  Thanks for the pointer :)